# How to set TLS version on apache HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

How can I change the supported TLS versions on my HttpClient?

I'm doing:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.1");
sslContext.init(
    keymanagers.toArray(new KeyManager[keymanagers.size()]),
    null,
    null);

SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, new String[]{"TLSv1.1"}, null, null);
Scheme scheme = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(scheme);
BasicClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
```

But when I check the created socket, it still says the supported protocols are TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

In reality I just want it to stop using TLSv1.2, for this specific HttpClient.

Comment: What version of HttpClient are you trying to target?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The solution is:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
    .useTLS()
    .build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory f = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
    sslContext,
    new String[]{"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1"},   
    null,
    BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(f)
    .build();
```

This requires org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient 4.3.x though.

Comment: It seems that this has been deprecated. Can you please update to reflect new httpClient versions?

Comment: I know. Unfortunately I didn't investigate too much on how to get it working with the new httpClient version, so I'm using an old version.
But let me know if you get it working.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I applied this solution to force calls to use TLSv1.2 since vendors like PayPay and UPS' API are now enforcing it.  Java7 defaults to TLSv1, Java8 defaults to TLSv1.2 but I can't upgrade Java right now, so this post really helped me.

Comment: What if I want to do something similar with httpclient 4.1.1?

Comment: @Oliveira does setting system environment https.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1 not achive the same result ?

Comment: @GauravRawat maybe. But then you change it for all the http clients, instead of just one.

Comment: That can still be done by using  SSL connection socket factory.getSystemSocketFactory and be managed for the app easily, that shouldn't charge it for all but it's UpTo your choice anyways

Comment: @AntonioOtero  did you get it working with JDK7 ? I created client using above method.But I see that during SSL handshake (ClientHello) the protocol listed is TLSv1. I did set https.protocols also but no effect.Using httpclient-4.3.3.jar. Do you mean that this only changes the supported protocol on socket but the underlying SSL handshake is still controlled by JSSE API ? I mean Apache HttpClient does not implement any of the TLS protocol aspects. It relies on JSSE APIs to do TLS/SSL handshaking and to establish secure SSL sessions ?

Comment: @ShrikantThakare I didn´t have those problems, I see TLSv1.2 listed. The only change I did to the code in this answer was to remove TLSv1.1 from the parameters of the factory, i.e.   new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}  Hope this helps

Comment: @Oliveira When you use `HttpClientBuilder`, this will work only if you enable `systemProperties` since it's off by default.

Comment: what is useTLS()? what should be implementing in this?any idea?

Comment: @DharmaKshetri https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html#useTLS()

Comment: @ShrikantThakare which version and build of Java did you use, please?

Answer (score 15):

This is how I got it working on httpClient 4.5 (as per Olive Tree request):

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, 443),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.user, this.password));

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createDefault();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
        new String[]{"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1"},
        null,
        new NoopHostnameVerifier());

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
        .build();

return httpclient;
```

Comment: Please note that the code snippet above uses NoopHostnameVerifier which essentially turns hostname verification off. In most cases, this is a very bad thing.

Comment: Can one just use the org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier ?

Answer (score 10):

HttpClient-4.5,Use TLSv1.2 ,You must code like this:

```
 //Set the https use TLSv1.2
private static Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> getRegistry() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    return RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
            .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .build();
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        //Set the https use TLSv1.2
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(getRegistry());
        clientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        clientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(clientConnectionManager).build();
        //Then you can do : client.execute(HttpGet or HttpPost);
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the `HttpClientBuilder` in HttpClient 4.5.x with a custom `HttpClientConnectionManager` with the defaults of `HttpClientBuilder` :

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = 
    new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.createDefault(),          
                                   new String[] { "TLSv1.2" },                                            
                                   null, 
           SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager =
    new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
        RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                       .register("http",
                                 PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                       .register("https",
                                 sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                       .build());

// Customize the connection pool

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                                  .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
                                                  .build()
```

Without a custom `HttpClientConnectionManager` :

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = 
    new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.createDefault(),          
                                   new String[] { "TLSv1.2" },                                            
                                   null, 
           SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                                  .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                                                  .build()
```

Answer (score 5):

For HttpClient-4.1 using TLSv1.2, code would go something like this:

```
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
        Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);
        ClientConnectionManager cm =  new        SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);

       // Use client to make the connection and get the results.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using httpclient 4.2, then you need to write a small bit of extra code. I wanted to be able to customize both the "TLS enabled protocols" (e.g. `TLSv1.1` specifically, and neither `TLSv1` nor `TLSv1.2`) as well as the [cipher suites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite).

```
public class CustomizedSSLSocketFactory
    extends SSLSocketFactory
{
    private String[] _tlsProtocols;
    private String[] _tlsCipherSuites;

    public CustomizedSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext,
                                      X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier,
                                      String[] tlsProtocols,
                                      String[] cipherSuites)
    {
        super(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);

        if(null != tlsProtocols)
            _tlsProtocols = tlsProtocols;
        if(null != cipherSuites)
            _tlsCipherSuites = cipherSuites;
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareSocket(SSLSocket socket)
    {
        // Enforce client-specified protocols or cipher suites
        if(null != _tlsProtocols)
            socket.setEnabledProtocols(_tlsProtocols);

        if(null != _tlsCipherSuites)
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(_tlsCipherSuites);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    sslContext.init(null, getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

    // NOTE: not javax.net.SSLSocketFactory
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new CustomizedSSLSocketFactory(sslContext,
                                                         null,
                                                         [TLS protocols],
                                                         [TLS cipher suites]);

    Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

    ConnectionManager cm = new BasicClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cmgr);
    ...
```

You may be able to do this with slightly less code, but I mostly copy/pasted from a custom component where it made sense to build-up the objects in the way shown above.

Comment: @Skynet The technique should be valid, but the specific TLS protocols and cipher suites are generally dictated by the underlying JVM. So you'll have to check out the protocol support for Android < 4.1.

Comment: @comeOnGetIt Java 6 mostly does not support anything higher than TLS 1.0 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6). Java 6 should be dead at this point, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) class reference in your code, you can set the enabled TLS protocols by a call to [SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledProtocols-java.lang.String:A-):

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.net.*; 
...
Socket socket = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
...
if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
   // "TLSv1.0" gives IllegalArgumentException in Java 8
   String[] protos = {"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"}
   ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(protos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 JVM argument didn't work for me. What worked is the following code

```
RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
//other configuration, for example
requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(1000);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create().useProtocol("TLSv1.2").build();

HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
builder.setProxy(new HttpHost("your.proxy.com", 3333)); //if you have proxy
builder.setSSLContext(sslContext);

HttpClient client = builder.build();
```

Use the following JVM argument to verify

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Comment: `-Dhttps.protocols` also works with Apache http client together with [useSystemProperties()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#useSystemProperties())

Answer (score 1):

You could just specify the following property -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 at your server which configures the JVM to specify which TLS protocol version should be used during all https connections from client.

Comment: Nope. Does NOT work server side, only in client side JVM Applets / Webstart.

Comment: It does not seem to work as well if you use the apache httpclient (tested with 3 and 4). I am not sure if these settings are really necessary if the other solutions are implemented.

Comment: Yes, if JDK makes the connection using `URL#openConnection()`, but these doesn't work with Apache HttpClient. Question is specifically tagged _apache-httpclient-4.x_

Comment: This also works with Apache http client together with [useSystemProperties()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#useSystemProperties())

Answer (score 0):

Since this only came up hidden in comments, difficult to find as a solution:

You *can* use `java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1`, but you need to use also [useSystemProperties()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#useSystemProperties())

```
client = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties();
```

We use this setup in our system now as this enables us to set this only for some usage of the code.
In our case we still have some Java 7 running and one API end point disallowed TLSv1,
so we use `java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` to enable current TLS versions.
Thanks @jebeaudet for pointing in this direction.