# Java, Apache HttpClient, TLSv1.2 & OpenJDK 7

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, java

We have a small group of Tomcat servers running OpenJDK v1.7.0_111. We have plans to upgrade them and migrate them this summer but we've found that a client API we interact with is moving to require TLSv1.2 in the near term. My ultimate desire is to find a configuration change to allow for this.

The application hosted there creates it's SSL context in a pretty straight forward way:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createDefault()
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
```

`SSLContexts` is from Apache's httpclient library (version 4.4.1) and is also pretty straight forward with how it creates the SSL context:

```
public static SSLContext createDefault() throws SSLInitializationException {
    try {
        SSLContext ex = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ex.init((KeyManager[])null, (TrustManager[])null, (SecureRandom)null);
        return ex;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException var1) {
        throw new SSLInitializationException(var1.getMessage(), var1);
    } catch (KeyManagementException var2) {
        throw new SSLInitializationException(var2.getMessage(), var2);
    }
}
```

And digging through the `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` class, it appears that it's simply using the `SSLSocket.getEnabledProtocols()` method to determine which protocols are available for use. Note that `this.supportedProtocols` is null in my case.

```
public Socket createLayeredSocket(Socket socket, String target, int port, HttpContext context) throws IOException {
        SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket)this.socketfactory.createSocket(socket, target, port, true);
        if(this.supportedProtocols != null) {
            sslsock.setEnabledProtocols(this.supportedProtocols);
        } else {
            String[] allProtocols = sslsock.getEnabledProtocols();
            ArrayList enabledProtocols = new ArrayList(allProtocols.length);
            String[] arr$ = allProtocols;
            int len$ = allProtocols.length;

            for(int i$ = 0; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
                String protocol = arr$[i$];
                if(!protocol.startsWith("SSL")) {
                    enabledProtocols.add(protocol);
                }
            }

            if(!enabledProtocols.isEmpty()) {
                sslsock.setEnabledProtocols((String[])enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]));
            }
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that while running a few preliminary tests I'm unable to get these clients to connect to an API requiring TLSv1.2.

In the following example I can get the `URLConnection` code to complete by including the `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` parameter, but I cannot get the Apache connection to connect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String testURL = "https://testapi.com";

        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslcontext.init(null, null, null);

        try {
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext);
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(testURL);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            System.out.println("Response Code (Apache): " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Apache HTTP Client Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(testURL).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
            urlConnection.connect();
            System.out.println("Response Code (URLConnection): " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("HttpsURLConnection Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Along with the `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` I've tried the `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` and the `-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true` JVM parameters without any luck.

Does anyone have thoughts to how to enable TLSv1.2 in this configuration without upgrading to v8 or changing the application to specifically request an instance of TLSv1.2?

Comment: Have you tried the params and tests shown here https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-8-will-use-tls-12-as-default

Comment: Additionally you might want to include a short [MCVE] so other users on JDK 7 can reproduce what you're attempting.

Comment: You should not enable all the supported protocols, as they include the insecure anonymous cipher suites.

Comment: @pvg - Now I have. I've listed all the JVM parameters I've tried in the question. I've also included a short example.

Comment: One last thing to throw in your sample, for the sake of completeness, might be a plain URLConnection test so you know it's not (or is) an httpclient-specific problem.

Comment: @pvg Great point. It appears to be something specific to httpclient.

Comment: Ah that narrows it down some, maybe this is a dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391798/how-to-set-tls-version-on-apache-httpclient

Comment: @pvg Close, but my goal is to fix this with configuration. I'd love to avoid manually specifying TLSv1.2 in the "getInstance" request since that would inclure another code change when the servers are update, new protocols are introduced, etc.

Comment: TLS 1.3 is a ways off. You'll be on JDK 8 before that so this might be a reasonable temporary  trade-off/fix.

Comment: Very fair. And that may end up being the route we end up going. But just covering my bases and see if we can avoid a code change.

Comment: @EJP: the anonymous ciphersuites (and also the null-encryption ones) are ciphersuites not protocols; enabling/disabling protocols has no effect on ciphersuites (except that some ciphersuites are only _used_ if TLS1.2 is enabled locally _AND negotiated by the peer_). Even SSL3 is really insecure only if attacker can repeat adaptively chosen plaintext, which is easy for browsers but not _most_ API clients.You can cause alarms by mistakenly enabling SSLv2Hello, but not actual insecurity because it can't actually do SSL2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`jdk.tls.client.protocols` only works on Java 8 (and presumably 9) which you aren't using.

`https.protocols` only works by default in `HttpsURLConnection` which httpclient doesn't use.

`deployment.*` only applies to JNLP and applets (if any browser still permits applets) which you aren't using.

An answer to your Q as stated, at least for 4.5, *assuming* you use `HttpClientBuilder` or `HttpClients` (which you didn't say), is to use `.useSystemProperties()` or `.createSystem()`, respectively; these *do* use the same system properties as `*URLConnection` -- or at least many of them including `https.protocols`. You should check none of the other properties included in this set is configured to do something you don't want. This *does require changing the apps, but not* changing them 'to specifically request ... TLSv1.2'.

Other than that you can configure the `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` to specify the exact protocols allowed as in [the Q linked by @pvg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391798/how-to-set-tls-version-on-apache-httpclient), or `SSLContexts.custom().useProtocol(String).build()` to specify the upper bound -- which is enough for your case because offering the range 'up to 1.2' to a server that requires 1.2 will select 1.2.

Comment: `jdk.tls.client.protocols` should actually be available in OpenJDK 7u91 and higher and 6u115 and higher if I am understanding [this OpenJDK enhancement request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076369) correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the recommended way of configuring Apache HttpClient 4.x to use a specific TLS/SSL version

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault(), new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()))
    .build();
```

Vote up to dave_thompson_085's answer