# calling `apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient` 3.1 with TLSv1.2

Tags: java, ssl, networking, tls1.2, apache-commons-httpclient

i am calling a SOAP server with `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient` 3.1 . Here is snippet of my code :

```
    URL targetURL =
                    new URL(msgContext.getStrProp(MessageContext.TRANS_URL));



    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(this.connectionManager);

    httpClient.getParams().setConnectionManagerTimeout(this.clientProperties.getConnectionPoolTimeout());

    HostConfiguration hostConfiguration = 
                    getHostConfiguration(httpClient, msgContext, targetURL);
    Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(msgContext.getUsername(), msgContext.getPassword());
    httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(msgContext.getStrProp(MessageContext.TRANS_URL), 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), defaultcreds);
    httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
    httpClient.executeMethod(hostConfiguration, method, null);
```

However I am getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake` exception.

I tried to fix it by creating a trust manager that does not validate certificate. but the error persists.
Is there any other method to call it using TLSv1.2 or by-pass ssl security?

Comment: Maybe you can get some help here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391798/how-to-set-tls-version-on-apache-httpclient

Comment: AFAIK apache commons does just use the SSL/TLS implementation of the JRE. Therefore the most important fact is the used JRE version (which you did not include in your question)

Comment: I am using JRE 1.7

Comment: You need at least 1.7.0_131-b31 for having TLS1.2 enabled by default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157422

Comment: can it be done by code change?

Comment: Thanks @Robert for suggesting this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157422. It works now.