# How can I set the tls protocol to httpclient

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I' am working with java 7 and I have in my code `HttpClient client = new new DefaultHttpClient();`
I have to use the tls protocol. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set TLS version on apache HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391798/how-to-set-tls-version-on-apache-httpclient)

Comment: If you want a specific version or versions of TLS I concur with @Berger; in particular in free j7 if you want higher than TLSv1.0. If you just want _some_ TLS, modern versions of Java no longer support SSLv3 (because of 'POODLE') and thus accessing any `https` URL will use TLS.